# QT Write access violation

Tags: c++, qt, linked-list, qstring

Hey guys i'm trying to make linked list by procedural programming in cpp in QT and whenever i try to add something to the list i get this error:

`c:\users\marcin\documents\dev cpp\proc_list\proc_list.cpp:11: error: Exception at 0x13fc325cb, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0 (first chance)`

From what i've already read the problem should be that i try to access null pointer, but tried checking it already and it looks fine. Here's the faulty code:

```
void append_rec(QString name, int age, int number, float balance, item *first){
    item *newrec;
    item *temp;

    newrec = new item(this);
    temp = new item;

    newrec->next = NULL;
    newrec->name = name;
    newrec->number = number;
    newrec->balance = balance;
    newrec->age = age;
    temp = first;

    while(temp->next!= NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = newrec;
}
```

and the problem (as the debugger says pops out on the `newrec->next = NULL;` line. I'm just starting to learn cpp and seriously can't find the solution.

*EDIT*

Code for the item struct (for this assignment i'm not allowed to use classes):

```
#ifndef PROC_LIST_H
#define PROC_LIST_H

#include <qstring.h>

struct item{
    item *next;
    QString name;
    int age;
    int number;
    float balance;
};

void append_rec(QString name, int age, int number, float balance, item * first);
void display_list( item * first );

#endif // PROC_LIST_H
```

*EDIT 2*

The main window file to cover all the things i've do with my list.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "proc_list.cpp"

item *first = NULL;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_front_add_clicked()
{
    append_rec(ui->name_edit->text(),
               ui->age_edit->text().toInt(),
               ui->accnum_edit->text().toInt(),
               ui->balance_edit->text().toFloat(),
               first);
}
```

Comment: What is thw type of newrec->next? Can you share code for item class?

Comment: @t.m. yes sure, totally forgot about it :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the case in c++, but in c structs, if you use a struct's keyword in itself, you should explicitly write it as struct. I mean, write "struct item *next" instead of just "item * next".

Comment: How do you create the `first` item? What __exactly__ happens in `proc_list.cpp` line 11? Oh. Wait. How is `this` legal at that point? Also, why don't you use a `std::vector` or a `QVector` or a `QList`?

Comment: Why are you calling `newrec = new item(this);` when the `item` struct doesn't have such a constructor?

Comment: @t.m. tested it couple of times when i did linked list in C and this is fine, tried adding it anyway, but still the same error

Comment: On the first call to `append_rec`, the `first` argument is NULL, and so accessing the `next` member isn't possible and generates an error

Comment: @Zeta i added my mainwindow file to show where i create the first pointer, and i didnt use stuff you ask because i dont know them yet. Will definitely check them :)

Comment: @brm yeah the (this) was a mistake, got rid of it by now :) and yeah it is null, but the program doesnt even get to line using it, it throws me an error on assigning name to the created element

Comment: @Animu: If you manage to get your program working, I ___strongly___ recommend you to get it reviewed, for example at [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed was that you mentioned procedural programming, and then used the "this" pointer in a function. Simply remove it. You don't even have a constructor for the "item" struct to use.

Secondly, you do `temp = new item` item and immediately after you do this this `temp = first`. BAM memory leakage. But that's not a major problem.

Also notice your list base pointer is from the very start NULL and trying to dereference its member `temp->next` from your while may return garbage results and MAYBE evaluate to true even if its just garbage.
STL lists for example have an "end" pointer to avoid that sort of things, you could do that as well.
Hope I helped!

**EDIT:**

Well I managed to solve the problems in plain C++ but I may have did it overcomplicated.
I chose to use a pointer-to-pointer because when the list is empty we will be able to change the base pointer through the argument. However I don't think this is the optimal solution but it works. Note you now need to pass the item's address when calling from main.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct item{
    item *next;
    string name;
    int age;
    int number;
    float balance;
};

void append_rec(string name, int age, int number, float balance, item** first){
    item *newrec = new item;

    newrec->next = NULL;
    newrec->name = name;
    newrec->number = number;
    newrec->balance = balance;
    newrec->age = age;

    while(*first!= NULL) // The pointer we are pointing to isnt valid
        first = &(*first)->next; // Point to the next pointer in the list

    *first = newrec; // Change the value of the pointer we are pointing to
}
void display_list( item * first )
{
    item* temp = first;
    while ( temp != nullptr )
    {
        cout << temp->name << '\n';
        cout << temp->number << '\n';
        cout << temp->balance << '\n';
        cout << temp->age << '\n';
        cout << "<===================||=======================>";

        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

item *first = NULL;
int main()
{
    append_rec("something 1", 1, 1, 1.f, &first);
    append_rec("something 2", 2, 2, 2.f, &first);
    append_rec("something 3", 3, 3, 3.f, &first);
    append_rec("something 4", 4, 4, 4.f, &first);

    display_list(first);
}
```

Comment: i must admit i didnt see that problem, but fixed it, and it still gives me error. It comes up on 11 line when i want to assign name to newrec->name